# I want to pass index and show my all data to next screen

Tags: reactjs, windows, react-native

```
  **onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('details'{item})}**
```

How can I pass the index and show my all homescreen data to the next screen?
check the onPress in TouchableOpacty

```
    <FlatList
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    numColumns={2}
    
    data={this.state.data}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}

    renderItem={({item, index}) =>  (
                
  <TouchableOpacity style={{fontSize:30, color:'white', padding:20, borderRadius:20,  margin:10, width:"43%", marginTop:-25 }}
   onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('details'{item})}>
  <View >
    <Image style={{width:160, height:130, alignSelf:'center'}} source={item.Image} />
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white', fontSize:15}}>{item.title}</Text>
    <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize:11}}>{item.title2}</Text>
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white', fontSize:15}}>{item.price}</Text>
  </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>

    )
  }
      />
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

}
}

Here is the data
data:[ {
id: '1',
Image:require('E:/G-TechWork/ReactNativeWork/FoodFactory/images/4b.png'),
title:"Beef Burger",
title2:"Onion with cheese",
price:'$20.00',
},
]

Comment: react-navigation？

Comment: ============>yes

Answer (score 0):

Just use state.

```
 <NavLink to={{ pathname: "/Pathname", state: {yourIndex: index}}}>Path</NavLink>
```

You can then pick this up on the next page with

```
location.state.yourIndex
```

This does have its own limitations but I would need to know more of what you plan to do.

Comment: I want to show data to the next screen check the code again.